# Waiting for Network Image and CircularProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter

How to put a circularprogressindicator inside de Circleavatar that run during Network Image loading?

```
CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 60,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(data['imageUrl']), waiting this image....
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

```
CircleAvatar(
    radius: 60,
    child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: data['imageUrl'],
          placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
          errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
        ),
    ),
);
```

try this out.